# React Component not updating after adding new value in store

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux, react-router

So I am using react, redux and firebase for this small crud app, whenever a new employee is created I redirect to the home component which should display all the employees created including the new one. But the new employee isn't showing up after redirection from create employee. What seems to be the issue, essentially I want is for the Home component to update with the new data.

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import EmployeesList from '../employees/EmployeesList'
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { compose } from 'redux'
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    const { employees } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <EmployeesList employees={employees} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  // console.log(state)
  return ({
    employees: state.firestore.ordered.employees
  })
}
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect([
    { collection: 'employees', orderBy: ['createdAt', 'desc'] }
  ])
)(Home)
```

CreateEmployee.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { compose } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import { createEmployee } from '../../store/actions/employeeActions'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const styles = theme => ({
    bt_create: {
        margin: theme.spacing.unit,
        padding: '10'
    },
    input: {
        display: 'none',
    },
});

class CreateEmployee extends Component {
    state = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        department: '',
        salary: ''
    }
    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        // console.log(this.state)
        // TODO store state data in db
        this.props.createEmployee(this.state)
        this.props.history.push({
        pathname: '/'
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <br />
                <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit">
                    Create new employee
                </Typography>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <TextField
                        id="name"
                        label="Name"
                        defaultValue=""
                        margin="normal"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <TextField
                        id="email"
                        label="Email"
                        defaultValue=""
                        margin="normal"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <TextField
                        id="department"
                        label="Department"
                        defaultValue=""
                        margin="normal"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <TextField
                        id="salary"
                        label="Salary"
                        defaultValue=""
                        margin="normal"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" className="bt_create">Create</Button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        createEmployee: (employee) => dispatch(createEmployee(employee))
    }
}
export default compose(
    withStyles(styles),
    withRouter,
    connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)
)(CreateEmployee)
```

Create employee action

```
export const createEmployee = employee => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore()
        // TODO add employee here
        firestore.collection('employees').add({
            ...employee,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date()
        }).then(() => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'CREATE_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS',
                employee: employee
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_EMPLOYEE_ERROR', err })
        })
    }
```

Comment: You need to call back api which will fetch employees in Home component. The best place for this api call would be in componentDidMount method. So that whenever Home component is called will render latest employee list